# WPF custom drawing and transparency - how to optimize?

Tags: wpf, performance, drawing, transparency

I have a WPF application with a custom windows style (AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"). This window has a custom Peak Meter control which uses WriteableBitmap to draw data from DirectSound audio input.

I am using a bitmap with all levels drawn as colored rectangles (red/yellow/green/red) and when the audio arrives I just draw a black rectangle over my level meter form the top. It works fine on my machine (Windows 7, Pentium 4 single core). But it works bad on a laptop with Windows XP SP3 and integrated video.

I know that transparency effects have some issues on DirectX 9, but I have read the problem should be fixed in SP3. Still the call to _writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect takes 30-40% CPU on XP and sometimes it causes dropouts in audio (if USB audio is used, and those dropouts occur not in my application but somewhere in DirectSound<->drivers subsystem).

On Windows 7 the same app takes no more than 3% CPU and no audio dropouts noticed (but the CPU is actually weaker on the Win7 PC than on the laptop with XP).

I tried not to use AddDirtyRect but just draw a WPF Rectangle element over the Image with leds and set the height of the rectangle when new audio level arrives. What a surprise! Somehow changing the height of a Rectangle element takes noticeably less resources than calling _writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect for 100x20 pixel rectangle! Now on XP it took just 10-20% instead of 30-40% with AddDirtyRect.

But when I removed transparency effect from the window, finally also XP (and even on VirtualBox) went down to 2-6% CPU. Obviously transparency makes it really hard to redraw 20x100 rectangle 10 times per second.

I could live with no transparency in my application, but the problem is - the design uses rounded corner windows and I need to cutoff the area around them. But as soon as I set AllowsTransparency="False", the window shows the background color behind.

**So the main question is - how do I make the contents of the window to clip away the background of the window so the corners stay round without using XP-heavy transparency?**

I remember that I could do than even on a C++ Windows application just by setting a custom window region and not using any transparency (that was on a Windows 98 machine). Can the same thing be done on WPF?

Or maybe there is some trick how to make WriteableBitmap to use less resources on XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I did not find anything better, I used the old way: SetWindowRgn API.

It was a bit complicated because my application uses some animated slide-out parts which protrude out of the main window so I had to sync WPF animation with SetWindowRgn calls to make slide-out effect look as clean as possible. The result is not ideal but acceptable. And the main thing - no more high CPU and no audio dropouts.